# Singular state transition probability matrix in David Silver's UCL Lesson 2

Tags: reinforcement-learning, transition-matrix

I'm studying David Silver's second lesson on reinforcement learning: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfHX2hHRMVQ&list=PLqYmG7hTraZDM-OYHWgPebj2MfCFzFObQ&index=2 and the state transition probability matrix is defined as [image]

However, with this python code:

import numpy as np

P = np.matrix([[0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0], [0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0.2], [0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.4, 0, 0], \
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 0] ,[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

np.linalg.det(P)

I'm getting a determinant of 0 and thus a singular matrix.

The issue is that David then defines the Bellman Function to get the vectorized value functions as: 
[image]

And thus if P can't be inverted, neither can (1-gamma*P) and I can't get V. Any tip on what am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: Re "and thus:" that's incorrect.  For instance, when $\gamma=0$ obviously $1-\gamma P = 1$ is invertible.  Indeed, $1-\gamma P$ is invertible except for a small finite number of values of $\gamma.$

Comment: However, in the lesson David shows in the slides v values for gamma=0.9

Comment: There's no problem: $1-0.9P$ is invertible. The only values of $\gamma$ for which $1-\gamma P$ fails to be invertible are $1,$ $1.046604,$ $1.548519,$ $-1.073406\pm2.148352i,$ and $-3.039221.$  These are the reciprocals of the nonzero eigenvalues of $P.$

Comment: Thanks for your reply whuber. As you can see here: https://ibb.co/x7QH3F6 I'm getting that the determinant of 1-0.9*P is 0. Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Help me out with Python here (because I haven't used it in a decade): does `1-P` subtract $P$ from the $7\times 7$ identity matrix (ones on the diagonal, zeros elsewhere) or does it perhaps subtract $P$ from the ones matrix (equal to $(1,1,\ldots,1)^\prime\cdot (1,1,\ldots,1)$)?  I suspect it's the latter but the former is the intended meaning.

Comment: Thank you whuber! Turns out I'm rusty in both Python and algebra. You were indeed correct, 1-P was subtracting P from the 7*7 ones matrix. I managed to get David Silver's V for gamma=0.9. It is strange that David, in his slides, presents values for gamma=1 when in that case 1-P is a singular matrix. Do you have any idea of why is that possible?

Comment: http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching_files/MDP.pdf his slides are here, forgot to mention earlier

Comment: The formula is a shorthand for solving the equation $(\mathbb{I} - \gamma P)V = R.$  Sometimes that can be solved even when $\mathbb{I} - \gamma P$ is singular.  You can, for instance, take the limit as $\gamma\to 1.$ An efficient way to do this is to average $(\mathbb{I}-(1\pm\epsilon)P)^{-1}R$ for small $\epsilon;$ in this case $\epsilon = 10^{-2}$ gets you sufficiently close (even though the two solutions differ substantially!).

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get his results with  ϵ=10^-4. Thank you very much!